# Sum of grouped by rows using nested aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I have two tables

Product:

```
Res    ID    Code    Type
1      A      A-01    High
2      A      A-02    Medium
3      B      B-02    Medium
4      B      B-03    High
5      C      C-01    Low
6      C      C-03    Low
```

Reservation:

```
Res    ID    High    Medium    Low
1      A     3       0         0
2      A     0       5         0
3      B     0       4         0
4      B     3       0         0
5      C     0       0         4
6      C     0       0         3
```

I am trying to get the sum total of all values grouped by ID

I can get the sum total by Type grouped by ID using

```
select 
product.res,
product.type,
count(product.type),
case
    when product.type='high' then reservation.high
    when product.type='medium' then reservation.medium
    when product.type='low' then reservation.low
    else 0
end,

case
    when product.type='high' then reservation.high* count(product.type)
    when product.type='medium' then reservation.medium* count(product.type)
    when product.type='low' then reservation.low* count(product.type)
    else 0
end

from pallets

left join reservation
on product.res=reservation.res

group by 
product.id,
product.type,
product.res,
reservation.high,
reservation.medium,
reservation.low

by product.id, product.res
```

I know need to get the sum total of all values grouped By ID.
So What I'm looking for is

```
ID    Total
A     8
B     7
C     7
```

When trying to figure this out a keep running into nested aggregate errors.
I'm operating on Postrgres 9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping it is as simple as this. Let's take the example of reservations table:

```
create table reservation (res int, id char(1), high int, medium int, low int);
insert into reservation values
(1,'A',3,0,0),
(2,'A',0,5,0),
(3,'B',0,4,0),
(4,'B',3,0,0),
(5,'C',0,0,4),
(6,'C',0,0,3);

select id, sum(high + medium + low)
from reservation
group by id
order by id;
```

Result:

```
| id | sum |
|----|-----|
|  A |   8 |
|  B |   7 |
|  C |   7 |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb874/2

EDIT:

Assume the following data structure:

Reservation:

```
+------+------+------+--------+------+
| res  | id   | high | medium | low  |
+------+------+------+--------+------+
|    1 | A    |    3 |      0 |    0 |
|    2 | A    |    0 |      5 |    0 |
|    3 | B    |    0 |      4 |    0 |
|    4 | B    |    3 |      0 |    0 |
|    5 | C    |    0 |      0 |    4 |
|    6 | C    |    0 |      0 |    3 |
+------+------+------+--------+------+
```

Product:

```
+------+------+------+--------+
| res  | id   | code | type   |
+------+------+------+--------+
|    1 | A    | A-01 | High   |
|    1 | A    | A-01 | High   |
|    2 | A    | A-02 | Medium |
|    2 | A    | A-03 | Medium |
|    3 | B    | B-02 | Medium |
|    4 | B    | B-03 | High   |
|    5 | C    | C-01 | Low    |
|    6 | C    | C-03 | Low    |
+------+------+------+--------+
```

SQL:

```
select
  p.id,
  sum(case 
      when p.type = 'High' then r.high
      when p.type = 'Medium' then r.medium
      when p.type = 'Low' then r.low
      end) tot
from product p
inner join reservation r on p.res = r.res
group by p.id
```

Results:

```
+------+------+
| id   | tot  |
+------+------+
| A    |   16 |
| B    |    7 |
| C    |    7 |
+------+------+
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that simple. In the Product table, there can be multiple Codes associated to a Res

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the problem a little better. Let me put something together shortly.

Comment: My fault! Let me try to explain a little better. Res 2 could have A-02 through A-100. I need the overall count of those codes  then multiple that total by the correlating Type value in the Reservation table (98*5). And then add that total with the others for that specific ID. So for ID A, using the numbers in this example and the initial table, I am looking for a result of 101 which would come from (98*5)+(3*1)

Comment: Ah, I see! Good explanation. I'll see what I can come up with

Comment: I've added an EDIT to the answer. I have an example of product and reservation data and the output of a SQL. Does that look right?

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Awesome. When you get a chance, please feel free to mark the answer as accepted to give closure to the question